# CSS aligning divs to the right with AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I realise this kind of question has been asked before but I can't find one which relates to when you have dynamic content.

At the moment I have an ng-repeat that creates as many divs as there are currently in my array of objects. I want them to appear to the right of each other until the container they are in is full, then to start to appear underneath one another.

```
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <!-- Default panel contents -->
                <div class="panel-heading">Group 1</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class='contentWrapper ng-cloak'>
                        <div class='content'>
                            <ul class="thumbnails">
                                    <p>

                                        <div class="grow " ng-repeat="form in listOfForms" data-drop="true" ng-model='listOfForms' jqyoui-droppable="{index: {{$index}}}" ng-class="{}" style="font-size: 20px;">
                                            <div class="grow " data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="listOfForms" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},placeholder:true,animate:false}">{{form.name}}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </p>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a good way of going about this?

Comment: is the div has fixed height? - I think this is more css + html question

Comment: We need to see what this is supposed to look like. My first inclination is to say that `float:left` or `display:inline-block` has the behaviour by default.

Comment: css `float:left`, `display:inline-block` and clearfix to fix the container?